# keep character value between '0 and '9' on increment

Tags: c

I am looking for a decent one line c statement to keep a character between `'0'` and `'9'` on increment

What I have right now is this:

```
char c;
...
c = (((c % 48 ) + 1) % 10) + 48;
```

Is there a better way of dong this?

Comment: What's exactly 'better'? In terms of Readability? Obfuscation? Performance?

Comment: Performance. I should've mentioned that in the question :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'0'` instead of hardcoding its ASCII value. Also I like `c - '0'` better than `c % '0'`; it matches up with the `+ '0'` better.

```
c = (c - '0' + 1) % 10 + '0'
```

Comment: I there any benefit of using '0' over 48?

Comment: @Sourabh You should write `'0'` because you **mean** the integral value of the character `0`. Looking at the code after a couple of weeks would lead you to think "Why 48?".

Comment: @Sourabh Using `'0'` also means that your code will work even if you're not using ASCII.

Comment: just an fyi, this code only works if you initialize c to a character between 0 and `, if c is initialized to 'a'(97) this line of code will return '0' where your initial code would return '2'. Your initial code is more correct and not mathematically equivalent to this answer.

Comment: That won't be a problem as c will always be between '0' and '9' initially, but thanks for the heads up!